# Problems while upgrading to 15.10 with AMD driver

Tags: kernel, ati, fglrx, 15.10, proprietary

Now first to explain my situation:
I have upgraded from 15.04 to 15.10. I have Intel/Amd **hybrid** graphics. The AMD GPU that I have is the radeon HD 6490m. My laptop is a HP probook 4530s(if you need further specifications you can google them). Up until now I have used the proprietarym driver fglrx-updates together with the fglrx-pxpress package. After the upgrade to 15.10, my install has just hanged on the boot sequence. Also my  hard drive is encrypted with LLVM. I made sure I used the right password. All the kernels **do** boot from recovery. Also the old kernel from 15.04 **does** boot normally with functioning drivers. I have run apt-get update and apt-get upgrade which installed a new kernel which also hangs on boot. I have run fsck as well.

So I have heard that the AMD drivers do not support the latest kernels, however on the Q&A on chat one of the Canonical engineers told me it is fixed. Well after the issues today I have investigated the bug and there is a fix, however it is still in willy proposed.

So my questions are:

1)How do I activate the 'proposed' repositories, update only the fglrx drivers, maybe fglrx-pxpress as well, and then disable the 'proposed' repositories?

2)What are the potential problems if I just continue using the old kernel?
How do I modify Grub to use the old kernel as the default(until a new one comes and potentially fixes the issue)?

Please try to answer until night which is in approximately 7 hours from now on for me. Because at night I will consider 'nuking' my install and doing a fresh install. I would prefer not to do this however, because I have many valuable configs and applications installed at the moment. Like a nice working i3wm config. Many virtual machines as well. oh yeah and many steam games, it would be a big hassle to redownload those games again, because my internet connection is currently very weak and it barely goes above 200Kbps.
I am currently busy and away from home so I won't be able to post any logs at least for 2-4 hours.

Anyways thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I have activated the wily proposed repositories, upgraded fglrx-updates-core, fglrx-amdccle-updates, fglrx-updates and linux-firmware-nonfree.

After that I did:
sudo amdconfig --adapter=all --initial

And now it works, thank you guys anyways!